# Configuring Rebus in a .net core Worker Service (or a Console App)

Tags: .net-core, configuration, microservices, rebus

I have seen that Adding rebus in the ASP.NET Core execution pipeline is very neat using Startup.cs.
I wonder if there is a same neat way to do the same for Worker service or generally a console app.

Most .net core console apps I have seen are very simple demo applications.
Kindly if there is any concrete sample configuration using .net core console application.
Regards
Amour Rashid

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to add Microsoft's Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting package and build your background service as a `BackgroundService`:

```cs
public class MyBackgroundService : BackgroundService
{
    readonly IServiceCollection _services = new ServiceCollection();

    public MyBackgroundService()
    {
        // configure the bus
        
        services.AddRebus(
            configure => configure
                .Transport(t => t.Use(...))
        );
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using var provider = _services.BuildServiceProvider();

        // start the bus
        provider.UseRebus();
        
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

which you then add by going

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<MyBackgroundService>();
        });
```

in your startup.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Mogens,
Another way is to

var host =CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();

host.UseRebus();
host.Run();

Or in ConfigureServices method
....
var provider=services.CreateServiceProvider();
provider.UseRebus();

It helped me I could create Worker Services using rebus.